# A geometry problem regarding a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a trapezoid $ABCD$ where base $AD$ is twice as long as base $BC$. Let $APD$ be a triangle such that it doesnt belong to the plane of the trapezoid. Let $K$ be the middle of $PD$. Let $\alpha$ be a plane through $BC$ and $K$. Let $M$ be a point where this plane intersect $AP$. Question: Does the segments $MC$ and $BK$ bisect each other??

I am having hard time trying to visualize this problem. Is there any way to visualize this type of three dimensional geometry problems so I can see what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If the picture does not meet your requirement, let me know.

If the picture is OK, I think the green plane is a parallelogram.

Comment: Thank so much for the picture. By the way, what software do you use to make such graphs? How can we prove the green one is a parallelogram indeed?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy I use Geogebra. Tim provides an answer to your second question. Another name for the theorem used is "intercept and then midpoint theorem".

Answer (score 1):

This is actually from figure that Mick provided:

It is easy to show that $M$ is the midpoint of $AP$. Then by thales theorem, or similarity, we have that $MK \parallel AD$.
Also by similarity, $2MK = AD$. But its given that $2BC = AD$. So $MK = BC$

Now, $BC \parallel AD$ and $AD \parallel MK$. So this implies $BC \parallel MK$

We have shown that 1 pair of sides are equal and parallel to each other, a sufficient condition for the quadrilateral to be parallelogram.